# How to add class in div after clicking the div that has radio button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick, radio-button

Im having problem on how to add a class in a div where it has a radio button. What I want is when I clicked the div, the radio button inside the div will mark checked and also the div container of the radio button will have a background of red.

Here's my javascript code

```
$( document ).on( 'click', 'div#wrapper-radio', function(event) {
    if( $(this).find("input[type='radio']").prop("checked") == false){
        if($(this).hasClass('panelLink__item--radio-checked') == false ){
            $(this).find("input[type='radio']").prop("checked", true);
            $(this).addClass('panelLink__item--radio-checked');
        }
    }
});
```

The problem with my code is that, it will work on the first click but when I click on another div that has radio button, the class still remain. Below is the image

[out of my code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBnJf.png)

Can anyone help me what do I need to add in my code? Or is there another way to get what I want? Please advise

Comment: you want to change on div click or radio button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the class from every other elements. Can try this code.

`$('div#wrapper-radio').removeClass('panelLink__item--radio-checked');`

Full code here

```
$( document ).on( 'click', 'div#wrapper-radio', function(event) {
    if( $(this).find("input[type='radio']").prop("checked") == false){
        if($(this).hasClass('panelLink__item--radio-checked') == false ){
            $(this).find("input[type='radio']").prop("checked", true);
            $('div#wrapper-radio').removeClass('panelLink__item--radio-checked');
            $(this).addClass('panelLink__item--radio-checked');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try it now and I will update you afterwards

Comment: @SoorajChandran if you care to check the time of the "other" answer, you'll see that it was written *at the same time* as yours, not a "copy", which is, frankly a bit rude to state.  Given there's only once sensible answer to this question, it should be obvious that if two people answer at the same time, they will give the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case just want to style your radio buttons like that you can just use labels and css.

```css
label{
   padding: 5px;
   background-color: yellow;
   border-radius:5px;
}
input[type=radio]:checked+label{
    background-color:orange;
  }

input[type=radio]{
   display:none;
  }
```

```html
<input type=radio name=radio id="one" checked/><label for="one">One</label>
<input type=radio name=radio id="two"/><label for="two">Two</label>
<input type=radio name=radio id="three"/><label for="three">Three</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class from all the wrappers just before you add it to one:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', 'div#wrapper-radio', function(event) {
    if( $(this).find("input[type='radio']").prop("checked") == false){
        if($(this).hasClass('panelLink__item--radio-checked') == false ){
            $(this).find("input[type='radio']").prop("checked", true);
            $('div#wrapper-radio').removeClass('panelLink__item--radio-checked');
            $(this).addClass('panelLink__item--radio-checked');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks. it is working. your answer and @Sooraj Chandran are the same and they both worked.